Set custom trace ID with Spring Boot 3, Micrometer and OTEL
I have two proprietary microservices (A and B) and a third-party one (C), both consuming and producing Kafka events.

A produces event1, and B consumes it.

B processes event1 and eventually delegates some async work to C. Eventually C sends B a result, causing B to publish said result in event2.


Both of my services have these dependencies:
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
      <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

among other things.
So a traceparent header is attached to event1 and I can see a trace (I'm using Jaeger to visualize them) for the path described in point 1. In fact, by placing @Observed on methods down the chain in B I can see the trace context being propagated from the value of the traceparent header in event1 through the methods processing this event in B.
However, I am losing the trace context, since the request goes out of B, and into C, over which I do not have control. What I want to do is, in B, save the traceId from the traceparent  attached to event1 before the request is sent to C, then when the result is sent from C to B, inject the saved traceId in the fresh trace context started in B and make the new spans appear as if they are part of the original trace.
Does anyone have experience with distributed tracing in this kind of setup?
The only way I managed to get this working was:
public void methodInBProcessingResultFromC() {
    var traceId = getItFromWhereverItWasSaved();
    var contextWithCustomTraceId = tracer.traceContextBuilder()
            .traceId(traceId)
            .spanId(generateSomeRandomHexString())
            .sampled(true)
            .build();

    try (var sc = tracer.currentTraceContext().newScope(contextWithCustomTraceId)) {
      var span = tracer.spanBuilder().name("new-span-in-B").start();
      var future = kafkaTemplate.send(...);
      span.end();
      return future;
    }

KafkaTemplate is configured to pick up on the traceId I'm injecting here, so event2 is published with the correct traceparent and the entire flow becomes one trace, but this feels forced and I feel like I'm doing something wrong.
